# sequelize.js - how to find all items by nested elements attribute?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i have two tables, 'places' & 'photos'.
each place hasMany photos, and each photo has an attribute called user_id.

how can i findAll the places which have photos which have a specific user_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `includes` option in sequelize

```
places.findAll({ include: [{ models : photos , where : { user_id = xx} }] })
```

or You can use raw query